# Enable or disable Web Appbuilder widget based on logged user

Tags: javascript, web-applications, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-online

In my web application I am able to add widgets and also change the rights of widgets from confing.json file,But this change is permanently. And I want the property of the widget to be enabled or disabled programatically at the run time using java-script API.Please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just publish an appConfig object with the new configuration using the **appConfigChanged** event name.

Here is a sample code that you could paste in chrome console to see it working with your Web AppBuilder project:

```
var topic = require('dojo/topic')
function showWidget(widgetId, trueOrFalse) {
    var appConfig = getAppConfig();
    var widgetsFound = appConfig.widgetPool.widgets.filter( widget => widget.id === widgetId );
    if(widgetsFound.length > 1){
        throw Error('More than 1 widget with the same id ' + widgetsFound[0].id + '. ');
    }
    if(widgetsFound.length == 1){
        var widget = widgetsFound[0];
        widget.visible = trueOrFalse;
        topic.publish("appConfigChanged", appConfig, 'attributeChange', {});
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
showWidget(yourWidgetId, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you please tell which file to add this code in my web application